# Can I use nested AsyncTasks to load images in Andorid?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am building a simple app that queries a web service to get URLs for images that I want to download. Right now, I do this by running an `AsyncTask` that does the query, processes the XML to find the image URLs, and populates an `Object` with all those details.

I want to know if I can then use this `Object` inside `onPostExecute()` to create another `AsyncTask` that downloads all the images from the URLs in the object?

Here is my code...

```
protected SongObject doInBackground(LastFMClient... client) {
    LastFMClient lfmClient = client[0];
    SongObject track = lfmClient.getMusicMetadata();
    return track;
}

 protected void onPostExecute(SongObject response) {
    // create another asynctask here to download images from the URLs in response.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do the downloading also in the same `AsyncTask.doInBackground`?

Comment: I though of that, but doing that inside the same AsyncTask might make it execute for a longer time and I think AsyncTasks are supposed  to be used only for short running tasks ?

Comment: `AsyncTask` is for performing background tasks that may take long time to execute. It is perfectly fine to run all the long running tasks in the same `AsyncTask` if they belong to the same logical group (as it is in your case).

Comment: Just as long as you remember that your Activity may finish - and properly dispose of your long-running AsyncTask you should be fine (& guard against doing stuff in onPostExecute that tries to modify Views of a detached Activity).

Comment: @Jens is a detached Activity one from which the AsyncTask has not been called ? Because that is what I am going to do here. My AsyncTask has been called from a different activity and the images I download are going to be be displayed in another activity. If I can't modify the view in that activity from this AsyncTask , how do I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call other asynctask from the onpost method.